# why is source command not being run in .bashrc

Tags: 10.04, bash, bashrc

I have a source command which i have to manually run every time I open a new terminal.

`source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash`

Thus I added the command into the .bashrc file. However the does not seem to been ran as I still need to manually run the command for my application to function  properly.

I have added a echo command to ensure the the .bashrc file is being ran by the the terminal and it seem to be the case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you use for `source`? A script (which script) or a file from the system (which one)?

Comment: its used to run a bash script

Comment: So, when you use `source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash` in terminal is ok and when you put this line in `~/.bashrc` is not ok?

Comment: yup thats right

Comment: Can you post your `/opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash` file on http://paste.ubuntu.com/?

Comment: here you go http://paste.ubuntu.com/5975648/

Answer (score 1):

Are you launching your terminals with a login shell?

Does your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile contain `. ~/.bashrc`?

If you use gnome-terminal,

- Edit -> Profiles
- select your profile and click Edit
- on the Title andCommand tab, check "Run command as a login shell"

Comment: No I am not launching my terminals with a login shell. Yup my .profile contain `~/.bashrc`